# Apache POI excel sheet formula reference to another sheet

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have an excel sheet which has a formula reference to another sheet of the same workbook. 
Currently, I'm on Sheet 1 and trying to set a formula for a cell using `cell.setFormula(Sheet2[#All])`.

While I'm doing that, I'm encountering the following error :

> Specified named range 'Sheet2' does not exist in the current workbook. org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParseException
>   at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.parseNonRa nge(FormulaParser.java:569)
>   at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.parseRange able(FormulaParser.java:429)
>   at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.parseRange Expression(FormulaParser.java:268)
>   at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.parseSimpl eFactor(FormulaParser.java:1119)
>   at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.percentFac tor(FormulaParser.java:1079)
>   at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.powerFacto r(FormulaParser.java:1066)
>   at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.Term(Formu laParser.java:1426)
>   at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.additiveEx pression(FormulaParser.java:1526)
>   at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.concatExpr ession(FormulaParser.java:1510)
>   at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.comparison Expression(FormulaParser.java:1467)
>   at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.Arguments( FormulaParser.java:1051)
>   at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.function(F ormulaParser.java:936)

However, in the workbook, I have created the necessary sheet. The sheet name is `Sheet2`. But still the code is not able to refer to that sheet. Is there a way to fix this issue or any workaround?

Comment: Unless there's a mistake in the name, `Sheet2` is missing a space to match `Sheet 2`.

Comment: I'm sorry. There is a mistake in the post. It is actually Sheet2.

Answer (score 1):

`Sheet2` is not the same as `Sheet 2`. Rename `Sheet 2` to `Sheet2`.